# Translator package not working with polyglossia

Tags: xetex, siunitx, polyglossia, translator

As the title says, I can't get `translator` to work with `polyglossia`. I noticed the problem when trying to use `siunitx` with localisation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\setmainlanguage{swedish}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\begin{document}
\numlist{10;20;30}
\end{document}
```

The result is "10, 20 and 30" (the correct translation would be "10, 20 och 30"). I figured it was a problem with `siunitx`, however using `translator` directly doesn't work either:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{translator}
\setmainlanguage{swedish}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\begin{document}
\translate{help}
\end{document}
```

The result is "help" while it should be "hjälp".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell `translator` which languages you are using as package options, for example `\usepackage[swedish,english]{translator}`. Moreover, the list of predefined translations is very small (see http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/translator/translator-basic-dictionary-Swedish.dict), and *help* is not in it. Therefore you need to define the translation for that word manually.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[swedish,english]{translator}
\deftranslation[to = Swedish]{help}{hjälp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\setmainlanguage{swedish}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\begin{document}
\translate{help}

\numlist{10;20;30}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]